# a bug of JTable.columnMoved method

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

javax.swing.JTable has a bug, 
if we sort the table while a null valued cell is editing, 
and whose column class does not have a constructor with "new Object[] { new String() }" parameter, eg. Long.class, 
the JTable will throw an exception.

I think that because javax.swing.JTable tries to remove the cell editor twice;
So I plan to override the JTable.columnMoved method as:

```
@Override
public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
    if (isEditing() && !getCellEditor().stopCellEditing()) {
        if(getCellEditor() != null) { // In javax.swing.JTable, no this check point
            getCellEditor().cancelCellEditing();
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
```

I felt that's not good enough, since it's not friendly for code readers, they may know JTable well, and do not like my sub classes like this.
Is there a better solution? 
Thanks a lot.

When running the following codes, double click one cell (do not input anything) and then click the header, the exception will show up.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Long.class, java.lang.Long.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: +1 for [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: +1 for finding the bug - just a little nitpick: Long _has_ a constructor that take a String (if it wouldn't the start of the edit would fail silently and no editing would be possible) - the real culprit is the GenericEditor which fires twice (as pointed out by @Robin) So replacing the default editor with a better-behaved implementation might be a viable way out, for Number types f.i. the [NumberEditorExt](http://java.net/projects/swingx/sources/svn/show/trunk/swingx-core/src/main/java/org/jdesktop/swingx/table) in the SwingX project

Comment: It's a better idea, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with the code you provided. I blame the `JTable#stopCellEditing` implementation

```
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        String s = (String)super.getCellEditorValue();
        // Here we are dealing with the case where a user
        // has deleted the string value in a cell, possibly
        // after a failed validation. Return null, so that
        // they have the option to replace the value with
        // null or use escape to restore the original.
        // For Strings, return "" for backward compatibility.
        if ("".equals(s)) {
            if (constructor.getDeclaringClass() == String.class) {
                value = s;
            }
            super.stopCellEditing();
        }

        try {
            value = constructor.newInstance(new Object[]{s});
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            ((JComponent)getComponent()).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
            return false;
        }
        return super.stopCellEditing();
    }
```

You enter the first if, where `super.stopCellEditing` is called. The return value of this call is ignored. Then the `newInstance` call throws an exception, which is catched but then `false` is returned, no matter what the return value was of `super.stopCellEditing`. This sounds incorrect to me. I would log the bug with Oracle with the code you provided

Comment: do not understand for `DefaultTableModel` & `DefaultCellEditor`, could be interesting only in the case to restore the Editor with last know value before sorting, filtering, reordering

Comment: +1 good dig :-) Seem to remember that this particular bug had bubbled up recently on SO, but can't find it right now.

Comment: just a note (@newda or whoever might be interested): [fixed in JXTable](http://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-1535)

Comment: @kleopatra nice. Would be nice if Oracle had the same response time

Answer (score 3):

I can't see any issue, any bug, TableCellEditor is canceled properly on sorting and column reordering,

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableWithTimer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    private JTable myTable;
    private String[] head = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"};
    private Object[][] data = {{null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null}};
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    public TableWithTimer() {
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, head) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colNum) {
                switch (colNum) {
                    case 0:
                        return Integer.class;
                    case 1:
                        return Double.class;
                    case 2:
                        return Long.class;
                    case 3:
                        return Boolean.class;
                    default:
                        return String.class;
                }
            }
        };
        myTable = new JTable(model);
        myTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        myTable.setGridColor(Color.gray);
        myTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        myTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        myTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        scroll.setViewportView(myTable);
        frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableWithTimer tableWithTimer = new TableWithTimer();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: your example _does_ demonstrate the problem (jdk7, didn't try 6 but expect it failing there as well) - can't see how you can't see it :-)

Comment: @kleopatra interesting not I can't to reproduce on `Java7` & `WinXP`, AFAIK there isn't but for `LONG`, but for `DOUBLE` and `LONG` too have to some hack with `stopC...`, not `cancelC...`, maybe you & (@trashgood)

Comment: @kleopatra notice but still is not possible to search inside own comments, hehehe I have the same experiences with metaSO as you :-)

Comment: The jdk version is 1.7.0_09

Answer (score 1):

The issue - analyzed correctly by @Robin - has several aspects:

- stopCellEditing incorrectly firing an editingStopped even when returning false
- stopCellEditing firing twice if an empty value is accepted by the constructor

While the second is "just" violating its contract, the first has severe consequences:

- as noted in the OP's question: throwing an NPE if client code tries to really terminate the edit, that is first stop and on failure cancel. Ironically, the most visible appearance is in jdk7 table.columnMoved - where the formerly (up to jdk6) incorrect removeEditor is replaced by the Right-Thing.
- might lead to data corruption if the edit started with a valid value which is deleted while editing: the editingStopped event triggers the table to replace the valid value in the tableModel with null ...

Enough reason to fix in JXTable by different logic in GenericEditor (the fix can be used in a custom GenericEditor as well, no coupling to swingx: simply c&p core GenericEditor and replace its stopCellEditing with the following):

```
@Override
public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    String s = (String) super.getCellEditorValue();
    // JW: changed logic to hack around (core!) Issue #1535-swingx
    // don't special case empty, but string contructor:
    // if so, by-pass reflection altogether
    if (constructor.getDeclaringClass() == String.class) {
        value = s;
    } else { // try instantiating a new Object with the string 
        try {
            value = constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { s });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ((JComponent) getComponent()).setBorder(new LineBorder(
                    Color.red));
            return false;
        }
    }
    return super.stopCellEditing();
}
```